# Java, merging two arrays evenly

Tags: java, arrays, merge

What would be the best way to merge two arrays of different lengths together so they are evenly distributed in the new array?

Say I have the following arrays

```
 String[] array1 = new String[7];
 String[] array2 = new String[2];
 String[] mergedArray = new String[array1.length + array2.length];
```

I would want mergedArray to have the following elements

> *array1 array1 array1* **array2** *array1 array1 array1* **array2** *array1*

but if I were to change the size of the arrays to

```
 String[] array1 = new String[5];
 String[] array2 = new String[3];
 String[] mergedArray = new String[array1.length + array2.length];
```

then I would want it to be

> *array1 **array2** array1 **array2** array1* **array2** *array1 array1*

basically if it can be helped each `array2` element shouldn't be touching each other; exception if `array2` has a size larger than `array1`.

Answer (score 1):

I would divide the size of the larger array with the size of the smaller array. The value that is got would be where the element of the second array would be.

In you 1st example - Size of the larger array is 7 and the size of the smaller array is 2. So it would be 7/2 = 3. Therefore the elements of the second array would be at positions 3 and 6 in the merged array.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with user Junaid's answer. The idea is that, you are distributing elements of smaller array into the larger array by escaping a constant number of elements. If the arrays are equal in size, you are distributing elements of smaller array between the all consecutive elements of larger array, Here is the implementation, follow it please:

```
String[] array1 = new String[]{"d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "m"};
String[] array2 = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
int l1 = array1.length;
int l2 = array2.length;
int sectionSize = l1 / l2 + 1;
String[] mergedArray = new String[l1 + l2];
String[] larger = l1 > l2 ? array1 : array2;
String[] smaller = l1 < l2 ? array1 : array2;

int j = 0, k = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= mergedArray.length; i++) {
    if (i % sectionSize == 0)
        mergedArray[i - 1] = smaller[j++];
    else
        mergedArray[i - 1] = larger[k++];
}
```

Comment: I really liked the approach, readable code and takes into account that either array could be larger than the other one. Although, it doesn't work in all cases. First, the sectionSize should be calculated like larger.length/smaller.length +1, otherwise it always becomes 1 when array2 is larger than array1. Second, try to add two more elements to array2 and it will throw an IndexOutOfBoundException. Not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have **m** elements in `array1` and **n** elements in `array2`. What you want to do is to add an element from `array2` for each **m/n** elements from `array1`.

In your first example:

**m = 7, n = 2** - You added an element from `array2` for each 7/2 = 3 elements from `array1`.

In the second example:

**m = 5, n = 3** - You added an element from `array2` for each 5/3 = 1 elements from `array1`.

You can do something like this:

```
int counter = array1.length/array2.length;
int m = -1, j = 0;
for(int i=0, c=0;i<array1.length;i++, c++) {
   m++;
   if(c == counter) {
     resArray[m] = array2[j];
     j++;
     c = 0;
     continue;
   }
   resArray[m] = array1[i];
}
```

Comment: Wow such a simple answer. God I feel dumb. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Simple answers aren't always easy to come by!

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution also doesn't work for e.g. array1.length=8 and array2.length=5. Try it out: IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to just insert `array1.length / array2.length` elements from `array1` for every element you in insert from `array2`, but this might leave you with a long sequence of `array1` elements at the end of the new array if the arrays don't divide evenly (meaning the ratio of their lengths isn't an integer - the length ratio is going to be truncated to an integer and you won't insert enough `array1` elements as a result).

An alternative is to use a random number generator to select which array to choose from: take `rand(array1.length + array2.length)`, and select from `array1` if the resulting number is less than `array1.length`, else select from `array2`; for this to work you should update the lengths on each iteration (so it's `rand(array1.length - number_of_elements_already_removed_from_array1 + array2.length - number_of_elements_already_removed_from_array2)`)