# Trying to combine two arrays into one sorted array; code does not work when first array is smaller than second array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to complete a homework assignment where I am tasked with combining sorted arrays into one sorted array without using the sort() function, or any other predefined method.

The code I have is as follows:

```
    try {
        // get input from a file
        Scanner ourScanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        int numInArray1;
        int numInArray2;
        int [] array1 = null;
        int [] array2 = null;
        int [] array3 = null;

        int indexArray1 = 0;
        int indexArray2 = 0;
        int indexArray3 = 0;

        boolean run = true;

        // keep looking for more input
        while (ourScanner.hasNext()) {

            numInArray1 = ourScanner.nextInt();             // first int will be number of elements in array
            array1 = new int[numInArray1];                  // create array1 with proper quantity of space allocated

            for (int i = 0; i < numInArray1; i++) {         // puts certain number of int into the array as indicated by numInArray1
                array1[i] = ourScanner.nextInt();
            }

            numInArray2 = ourScanner.nextInt();             // next int after the integers put in the array will be number of elements in array2
            array2 = new int[numInArray2];                  // create array2 with proper quantity of space allocated

            array3 = new int[numInArray1 + numInArray2];    // create final array for both lists merged, allocate appropriate amount of space

            for (int j = 0; j < numInArray2; j++) {         // puts certain number of int into the second array as indicated by numInArray2
                array2[j] = ourScanner.nextInt();
            }
            //.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));

        }

        /*System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));*/
        while (run == true) {

            if (array1.length - indexArray1 == 1 && array2.length - indexArray2 == 1) {
                run = false;
            }

            if (array1[indexArray1] < array2[indexArray2]) {        // if element in array1 is smaller than in array2
                array3[indexArray3] = array1[indexArray1];      
                System.out.print(array3[indexArray3] + " ");
                indexArray1++;
                indexArray3++;

            }
            if (array1[indexArray1] > array2[indexArray2]) {        // if element in array1 is bigger than in array2
                array3[indexArray3] = array2[indexArray2];
                System.out.print(array3[indexArray3] + " ");
                indexArray2++;
                indexArray3++;
            }
            else if (array2[indexArray2] == array1[indexArray1]) {      // if the two elements are the same
                    indexArray1++;
                    System.out.print(array3[indexArray3] + " ");
                    indexArray3++;
                    array3[indexArray3] = array2[indexArray2];
                    indexArray2++;
                    System.out.print(array3[indexArray3] + " ");
                    indexArray3++;
                }
            if (array2.length - indexArray2 == 0) {
                int numLeft = array1.length - array2.length;
                for (int j = array1.length - (numLeft + 1); j < array1.length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(array1[j] + " ");
                }
                run = false;
            }
            else if (array1.length - indexArray1 == 0) {
                int numLeft = array2.length - array1.length;
                for (int k = array2.length - (numLeft + 1); k < array2.length; k++) {
                    System.out.print(array2[k] + " ");
                }
                run = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File not Found");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

My code works when the first array is larger than the second, but I get an error when the first array is smaller than the second.

I am not sure why this is happening, so any guidance or nudges in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *but I get an error*  - maybe useful information do you not think?

Comment: @ScaryWombat it works when I run it, what size arrays are you using? Even when I have the second array bigger than the first, it will still run for the first few elements and then run into an error.

Comment: it is you who is saying *but I get an error* - I want to know what error are you getting?

Comment: @ScaryWombat "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Comment: If you print out the stacktrace, it will even tell you what line the error is on

Comment: @ScaryWombat it says is happens at this line "if (array1[indexArray1] > array2[indexArray2]) { // if element in array1 is bigger than in array2" I am not exactly sure how to fix it as I am just starting out in Java, any ideas you have are much appreciated

Comment: Yes, but in that code you are exceeding the bounds of the Array, hence a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Is the idea of this exercise to create the merged sorted array while you process the two original arrays or can you merge and then sort them technically split up the merge and the sort?  By this time in programming classes you should have gone into making your own Qsort or recursive sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to use more elseif statements rather than so many if statements. Here is an example of where you could change it to an elseif statement instead of your original if statement.

```
        if (array1[indexArray1] < array2[indexArray2]) {        // if element in array1 is smaller than in array2
            array3[indexArray3] = array1[indexArray1];      
            System.out.print(array3[indexArray3] + " ");
            indexArray1++;
            indexArray3++;

        }
        else if (array1[indexArray1] > array2[indexArray2]) {        // if element in array1 is bigger than in array2
            array3[indexArray3] = array2[indexArray2];
            System.out.print(array3[indexArray3] + " ");
            indexArray2++;
            indexArray3++;
        }
```

Also, here is another question that is similar to yours: [Java, merging two arrays evenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353721/java-merging-two-arrays-evenly?rq=1)
Maybe there are more features mentioned in there that you could use for future reference.

Comment: Just needed another else if instead of if statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you should update hear

```
if (array1[indexArray1] < array2[indexArray2]) {        
    array3[indexArray3] = array1[indexArray1];
    System.out.print(array3[indexArray3] + " ");
    indexArray1++;
    indexArray3++;

} else if (array1[indexArray1] > array2[indexArray2]) {  // Update hear. Use else if instead of else.
    array3[indexArray3] = array2[indexArray2];
    System.out.print(array3[indexArray3] + " ");
    indexArray2++;
    indexArray3++;
}
```

I have run your code, but logic may be have error. So I'm not sure that will help you.